# bulk change of certain nodes in OSM file

Tags: openstreetmap

How to I change a OSM file in multiple nodes and just change the value i.e. aminity=townhall into aminity=school?
Please suggest.

Comment: Please give us more details. Otherwise I would suggest a simple [OSM RW lib](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Data_Processing_or_Parsing_Libraries), XSLT script or just a simple text processor as sed.

Answer (score 0):

I created parser to modify the XML nodes I wanted to change. marked those nodes as changed. and saved as a new JSON XML file. Loaded the change XML and JSON happily uploaded it. it worked perfectly.